What could have resulted in successful restore and dbcc check, but with missing data file (ndf)?
I faced a wierd backup/restore issue.
Source server: SQL server 2019 CU27
Target server: SQL server 2022 CU14
There is a database on SQL Server 2019 having 2 data files (MDF and NDF).
We did a compressed full backup of this db. Copied the file over to the SQL server 2022, and performed a restore, followed by a successful dbcc check.
Everything was OK until a user complained missing data. That is when we realised that one data file is missing. We performed another dbcc check for sanity. It was successful. We did not investigate further and performed a fresh compressed backup and restore. The restore correctly created 2 data files.
What could have possibly gone wrong to cause this missing data file issue? I cannot replicate this behaviour. And we don't have the original backup file used by the on call DBA to perform this activity.

Did the original restore occur on a server where a database with that name existed already?

Yes correct. But we didn't check the if the db had 1 or more data files. Most likely it would have had 2. But can't say for sure.

My guess is that you have more than one backup in the file. Ure RESTORE HEADERONLY to verify. I. e you restored an older backup. Another thing you can check is how many file groups you have. It is possible to exclude file groups when you restore, less likely though.

Are you saying one backup (from the backup file) had only one data file?

There is only one file group called PRIMARY

@J.D. - the answer to Did the original restore occur on a server where a database with that name existed already?  is YES. Can you tell me more about this please as to how this may be related to the issue.

If your compressed full backup was not performed WITH INIT, then probably:

it was appended to an existing backup file that already had  other full backups in it
one or more of those backups - at least the initial one - had been taken before the second data file was added
when you performed a restore, unless you specified FILE = n (where n is the most recent), it will have defaulted to the first file, which is the oldest

This would explain why the on-call DBA saw the original symptom and would also explain why taking a new backup to a new backup file would not reproduce the issue. Other than confusion / restoring the wrong database altogether, I can't think of any other cause for a data file to simply be missing, yet everything is successful.

we don't have the original backup file

It would be easy to reproduce if you still had that backup file. Curious to know what happened to it? Did someone delete both the source and the copy? Covering their mistake/tracks maybe? The backup commands may still be in msdb on the source server, so you could check if multiple backups were made to the same backup file. You also might still be able to figure out exactly when the ndf was added (file properties in Windows, or default trace) and correlate that to the times of the backups you found in msdb.
Also, maybe, vet your on-call DBAs better. If they performed the backup and can't understand or troubleshoot what happened, they probably shouldn't be responsible for your backups. Doesn't sound like it was the end of the world in this specific case, but this is hardly the worst kind of thing that could happen with inexperienced people at the helm.

it was appended to an existing backup file that already had other full backups in it - Let's say the db name is ABC. By other full backups do you mean another database's full backup (example: XYZ db that has one data file only)? Or do you mean backup of one of the ABC's data files (I'm not sure this is a possibility)?

@variable I mean BACKUP DATABASE ABC TO DISK = 'C:\whatever\file.bak';, waiting a minute, and again doing BACKUP DATABASE ABC TO DISK = 'C:\whatever\file.bak';. There is only one database involved, but file.bak will contain two full backups of that database from two different points in time. If you add a data file in between, only one of the backups will have any knowledge of that data file, and if you restore without specifying that backup, you won't get it.

Ok surely this wasn't the case. The DBA restored the backup file have both data files. Infact the error log said that there was an error restoring the ndf file (second file). I will find the exact error msg tomorrow and paste it in this question.

@variable If there was an error restoring the ndf file then the entire restore operation would have failed. Which means your colleague was looking for data in whatever copy of the database existed on that server before you even tried to restore. That's why J.D.'s question is relevant. If there was an error during restore, then maybe your question shouldn't say "Everything was OK until..."
